# confusions about mutable keyword in lambda expression

Tags: c++, lambda

In C++ Primer the book says if we want to change the variable captured by value, we should add "mutable" ketword behind the parameter list. However, I found some problems when I write some codes to test this rule.
First I write the codes below:

```
//case1:
int val = 5;
auto f1 = [val]() mutable {return ++val;};
cout << f1() <<endl;

//case2:
int val = 5;
auto f2 = [val]() mutable {return val+5;};
cout << f2() <<endl;
```

I get correct return value as expected. The first block of codes returns 6 and the second returns 10.
However, as I want to test whether the "mutable" keyword is really useful as descirbed in the book, I delete the "mutable" keyword in both blocks of codes.

```
//case1:
int val = 5;
auto f1 = [val]() {return ++val;};
cout << f1() <<endl;

//case2:
int val = 5;
auto f2 = [val]() {return val+5;};
cout << f2() <<endl;
```

**As expected, case1 compilation failed. However, case2 can still compile success and return 10!** I got confused and I don't know what happened behind the case2. From the case1, I see the "mutable" keyword really useful. However, from the case2, althougth there's not a "mutable", I can also change the value of the variable 'val'. Who can tell me what happened? Is there something I ignore?

Comment: You're just returning `val+5`, not changing the value of `val`, it's still `5`.

Comment: I see, I may ask a foolish question.  Thanks！

Comment: Try to call the lambda twice.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
int val = 5;
auto f1 = [val]() mutable {return ++val;};
cout << f1() <<endl;
```

is equivalent to:

```cpp
int val = 5;
struct f1_t {
    mutable int val;
    f1_t(int v): val(v) {}
    int operator()() const {return ++val;}
};
auto f1 = f1_t(val);
cout << f1() << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

++val is increasing val itself which would change val. But if you do val + 5, everything that happens is that a temporary int object of the value 10 is created and then returned, but val actually never changes so its perfectly valid.